# How manage several folders in my domain?

Tags: apache, dns

I want create subdomains like this:

```
domain.com/type/city
```

An examples:

```
domain.com/restaurants/new_york
domain.com/hotels/new_york
domain.com/restaurants/chicago
```

I have thousand of cities in a mysql database.

I thinked in some options:

- Thousand of folders with an index.php for redirect (I think wrong way).
- Create an sitemap with all links (domain.com?type=hotels&city=chicago) and manage they by code with the database.
- Apache?

Please, which will be the best way for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You most probably mean subdirectories, not subdomains. A subdomain is city.example.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a combination of PHP and Apache configuration. That is the most common solution and seen in popular PHP website software such as Drupal and Wordpress.

The idea is to let Apache send all traffic to one index.php file and pass the rest of the path as a parameter for PHP to handle with it.

You will need to be carefull with a few edgecases though; if file such as ./public/styles.css is requested, you don't want to serve that trough your PHP application but want apache to serve the file directly. *Existing files will need to be handled by apache, all else by you application*.

In your *.htaccess*:

```
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first line tells Apache to send normal files by itlself. Second line does the same for existing directories. Third line avoids that browsers (most notably version IE6) who request the example.com/favicon.ico don't hammer your PHP application.

Then it passes everything along to `index.php` and adds the rest of the path into the q param.

Inside index.php you can then read that, and take action with that:

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['q'];
$params = explode('/', $path);

print $path;
print_r($params);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of folders would be the wrong way that is for sure.

If you start creating the sitemap with links of the type domain.com/?type=hotels&city=chicago you get a nice structure that you can manage programatically.

First get this started and working, then look up .htaccess and mod_rewrite which you can then use to map from domain.com/type/city to your links already functioning.

This seems both to be a good strategy for getting something working fast, and for ending up with the prettiest solution.